# Equals sign in django-registration activation url

Tags: django, django-registration

I am using django-registration and for some reason, when it sends the activation email, it inserts an equals sign in the third to last character as such: http://example.com/accounts/activate/a65b4aca5156211bc522e29f3e872290544d14=
e4/

This means the URL dispatcher does not catch the URL (the regex is `^activate/(?P<activation_key>\w+)/$`. The url is incorrect anyway, as it should be without the equals sign.

Anybody know why this is happening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your email client isn't reading the quoted-printable-encoded message properly. A `=` at the end of a line means that the line should be concatenated with the following line seamlessly.

Comment: My guess is that the OP is seeing this message in their debug log.

Comment: This was helpful. I was seeing this message in Django's test mail server (on terminal) :) Thanks.