# django-registration activate url matching

Tags: regex, django, django-forms, django-registration

I'm implementing the django-registration package to my project. Everything worked smoothly but when you go to the link sent to the email with the activation key in the URL, django doesn't match any URL to the given URL.

The generated URL sent by email is

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/activate/23c768c78ecd7af9b1516e37013901fd9ea=0b062/
```

and one of the URL that django tries to match it with is:

```
^accounts/ ^activate/(?P<activation_key>\w+)/$ [name='registration_activate']
```

but apparently it doesn't match. Any ideas what might be wrong?

My main urls.py contains

```
(r'^accounts/', include('registration.urls'))
```

and in registration.urls has

```
url(r'^activate/(?P<activation_key>\w+)/$',
                       activate,
                       name='registration_activate')
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equals sign in django-registration activation url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293289/equals-sign-in-django-registration-activation-url)

Answer (score 0):

i don't think `=` is an alphanumeric character that `\w` would match you will have to add `=` to your regex.

also the carrot ^ denotes a the start of the field so

```
^accounts/activate/(?P<activation_key>\w+)/$ [name='registration_activate']
```

would work.  Unless you are saying that ^accounts is in your main urls.py and ^activate is in an included urls.py in which case your question is a little confusing to me.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution on [Equals sign in django-registration activation url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293289/equals-sign-in-django-registration-activation-url)
The problem was that my mail "client", in cmd was adding a '=' sign to concatenate lines.

Thanks